# OSGi Remote Service Admin and security context

Tags: osgi, dosgi

In our current system, the security context of principals invoking the REST APIs is stored in a ThreadLocal variable. The SecurityContext can be retrieved at any level of the execution path and any method signature in any service does not need to explicitly declare a SecurityContext parameter.

Now we would like to introduce OSGi Remote Service Admin (RSA) to distribute services across different OSGi runtimes and I'm wondering what is the right approach to follow: from the [RSA specs](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.remoteservices.html) I cannot see any support from RSA service in distributing the SecurityContext, am I right? On the other hand it would be nice to propagate the context without polluting the service method signatures.

Is there any pattern to follow to achieve this?